# How to install all the dependencies and plugins using package.json in ionic

Tags: json, node.js, git, ionic-framework

I have cloned ionic project from git in which the node_modules, platforms, plugins are not available but in the package.json i am having all the detail so whether i have to install all one by one or is there any short way where i can use the package.json and install all the node_modules, platforms and plugins.

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=4.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "gulp build --minify && gulp karma"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.8.3",
        "chalk": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova": "^6.0.0",
        "del": "^2.0.0",
        "elementtree": "^0.1.6",
        "eslint": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.1.1",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.0.1",
        "gulp-changed": "^1.3.0",
        "gulp-csso": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
        "gulp-htmlmin": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.1",
        "gulp-inject": "^4.0.0",
        "gulp-jsonlint": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0-rc",
        "gulp-natural-sort": "^0.1.0",
        "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
        "gulp-protractor": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
        "gulp-shell": "^0.5.1",
        "gulp-size": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
        "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-useref": "^3.0.4",
        "karma": "^1.1.0",
        "karma-angular-filesort": "^1.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.3.0",
        "main-bower-files": "^2.9.0",
        "minimist": "^1.2.0",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
        "plist": "git://github.com/akofman/plist.js.git#3f256fd21ab3ad3ada0f491cfc905098a2631342",
        "proxy-middleware": "^0.15.0",
        "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
        "vinyl-paths": "^2.0.0",
        "wiredep": "^4.0.0",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.9",
        "yeoman-test": "^1.1.0"
    },
    "generator-m-ionic": {
        "proxies": [
            {
                "proxyMapFrom": "/postman-proxy",
                "proxyMapTo": "https://echo.getpostman.com"
            },
            {
                "proxyMapFrom": "/another-proxy",
                "proxyMapTo": "https://echo.getpostman.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "angular-multiple-select": "^1.1.2",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-ios": "~4.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "~1.1.5",
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": "~1.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1",
        "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "~2.6.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
        "pdfmake": "^0.1.31"
    },
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android",
            "ios"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: can you include package.json in question?

Comment: @SurajRao can u check the updated question pls

Comment: you have the latest ionic cli version?

Comment: @SurajRao do you want to know what version i am using?

Comment: yes..which is your ionic  **cli** version. Not the framework.. or have you not installed it?

Answer (score 17):

First install both ionic and cordova cli.(It is an ionic v1 project with android/ios platforms) from your package.json.

```
npm i -g cordova ionic
```

To install dependencies and devDependencies, do:

```
npm install
```

To install plugins and platforms as per package.json,

```
ionic cordova prepare
```

Comment: the ionic cli version is 3.4.0 and when i give the command ionic cordova prepare i am getting the message as you are not in project directory

Comment: you need to be in the project folder to run both npm install and ionic cordova prepare

Answer (score -2):

You may use the `npm install` command,
which will install all of the project dependencies locally.

**npm official docs description for `npm install` command:**

> This command installs a package, and any packages that it depends on.
>   If the package has a package-lock or shrinkwrap file, the installation
>   of dependencies will be driven by that, with an npm-shrinkwrap.json
>   taking precedence if both files exist. See package-lock.json and
>   npm-shrinkwrap.

[source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)